# Removing character from enumerate referenced item

Tags: enumerate

I set up my enumerated list with the character ")" so that it looks like this:
1)
2)
3)
and so on.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item text text text
    \item text text text \eqref{item:i1} or \eqref{item:i2}, text text text
        \begin{enumerate}[label=Step \roman*)]
        \item\label{item:i1} text text text
        \item\label{item:i2} text text text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get: (Step i)). I would like to have: (Step i)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If you want to use `\eqref` you can try `\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \roman*), ref=Step \roman*]`. But I would probably prefer `\ref` over `\eqref`, in which case `\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \roman*), ref=(Step \roman*)]` might be nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach `label` from `ref`; I made some other improvements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps]{
  label=Step \roman*),
  ref=Step~\roman*,
  labelwidth=\widthof{Step vi)},
  align=left,
  leftmargin=*,
  labelsep=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item text text text

\item text text text \eqref{item:i1} or \eqref{item:i2}, text text text
\begin{steps}
  \item\label{item:i1} text text text
  \item\label{item:i2} text text text
\end{steps}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]